# Как понять пословицу "Простота хуже воровства"?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, фразеология

**Так почему же простота хуже воровства?**

**ПРОСТОЙ** – общеславянское слово,  со значением  «стоящий впереди».  Такое же значение имеет слово **ПРИМИТИВНЫЙ** (от лат. primitivus) первоначальный, первобытный, простой, неразвитый.  Таким образом, с точки зрения этимологии это синонимы.

В современном языке слово «простой» – многозначное, но связь частично сохраняется, например: 10. Разг. **Недалёкий по уму, глуповатый, наивный.**  *Нельзя быть таким простым. Соблазнился от простого ума.*

**О такой простоте идет речь в пословице?** И почему подобная простота  так нехороша, что даже хуже воровства.

P.S.  Вопрос задан в связи с англоязычным правилом KISS:
*Keep it simple, stupid.*  Оно мне тоже кажется странным. О какой простоте говорится в нем?

Есть ли в русском языке пословица, **похожая по смыслу на это правило**, где говорится о положительной стороне простоты?

Comment: *Есть ли в русском языке пословица, похожая по смыслу на это правило, где говорится о положительной стороне простоты?* — конечно: *Всё гениальное просто.*

Comment: Спасибо (что же не в поле ответа). Но гениальность У НАС идет по особой статье и в нашей жизни встречается не часто. Если только в форме иронической приговорки, то да. А как у них, не знаю.

Comment: Может, стоит поправить название: это не фразеологизм, а пословица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой (*стоящий и действующий прямо*; *говорящий прямо*, *безыскусно*, *не красноречиво — от души*). В вопросах хозяйствования и жизнедеятельности такой может приносить убыток и опасность. Кроме того, его весьма сложно осуждать и карать. Сложнее, чем того же вора.

> Он, конечно, виноват, но он не виноват! Пожалейте его, товарищи судьи, он очень хороший человек!

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение

Answer (score 1):

Похожая поговорка:
*Всё гениальное просто[, а всё простое гениально].*
Здесь не о гениальности буквально, а о том, что ответ часто лежит на поверхности и он прост.

С правилом KISS более-менее всё ясно. Чем сложнее система — тем больше в ней ошибок, проблем, уязвимостей, тем сложнее её улучшать, анализировать, чтобы понять. А главное — тем меньше людей захочет и сможет поучаствовать в этом.

А вот с пословицей сложнее. Простота [невыпендривание] в народе ценится. Не стоит её путать с тупостью, хотя есть слово "простофиля": он не хотел ничего плохого, но его тупость привела к печальным последствиям (масштабы могут быть от незначительных до просто катастрофичных). А для наказания за преступление главное умышленные действия, а их нет, поэтому с вором проще.

Comment: Все гениальное просто, да только путь к этой простоте  непрост.  Обычно это нестандартный ход, в то время как другие вытаптывают давно исхоженные дороги.

Comment: Там больше не о гениальности, а о простом решении проблемы — когда говорят "точно, гениально!".

Comment: Не только, могут слишком усложнять и поэтому не находить решения. *Должны мы упрощаться по чужим моделям и стремиться к простоте* — смотря в чём.